# Toggle object property through mapped onPress event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

my onPress event is not toggling the object's property value "active" I'm not really sure why this isn't working.  The only other solution I can think of is referencing a common value in state?  Anyone able to explain why I cannot reassign the object value this way?

```
const priorities = [
    {
        title: "item A",
        active: false
    },
    {
        title: "item B",
        active: false
    }

{priorities.map((item, p) => {
    return(
        <View key={p}>
        <Button title={item.title} type="outline" 
            color={state.backgroundColor}
            size= {45}
            style={{marginLeft:40, backgroundColor: item.active === false 
             ?"red" : "green"}}
            onPress={() =>{item.active = !item.active}}                
            />
        </View>)
})}
```

Comment: you cant mutate array object directly on onPress function in reactjs or in react-native ,you have to call fucntion and change the arrays object value by using setState function

Answer (score 1):

I made some corrections to your code, hopefully this does what you wanted.

```
let checkActive = this.state.active;

{priorities.map((p) => {  return <View key={p}>
      <Button title={p.title} type="outline"
            size={45}
            style={{marginLeft:40, backgroundColor: checkActive ? 'red': 'green'}}/>
    </View>})}
```

set your state to what you want as default, to change colors, set your active state true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`onPress={() =>{priorities[p].active = !priorities[p].active}}`

But really you should handle these stuff with state.

Answer (score 0):

You should store an index of the pressed event in state and inside loop you should compare it with iteration index. This way you dont need to mutate objects.

`onPress={()=>this.setState({activeIndex:this.state.activeIndex===p?-1:p})}`

`style={{backgroundColor:this.state.activeIndex===p?"green":"red"}}`

Hope this can help you!